# DotFuscator Error

Tags: c#, .net, dotfuscator

I'm usin the 4.9 version of Dotfuscator, till yesterday the software wos working wll, but now, when I'm trying to obfuscate any project, I have this exception:

> Loading Assemblies...
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.A.0\Axoft.Apertura.ServiceHost.exe.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.Apertura.ServiceHost.exe"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.C.0\Axoft.Config.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.Config.dll"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.P.0\Axoft.Protection.Cryptography.Business.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.Protection.Cryptography.Business.dll"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.P.1\Axoft.Protection.Cryptography.Service.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.Protection.Cryptography.Service.dll"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.S.0\Axoft.SecurityApp.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.SecurityApp.dll"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~Axoft.T.0\Axoft.TangoNube.Common.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\Axoft.TangoNube.Common.dll"
>
> Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX
>   4.5.1 Tools\ildasm.exe /OUT="C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Ofuscado\Temp\~DBAcces.0\DBAccess.dll.il"
>   /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD
>   "C:\TangonetTools\Aplicaciones
>   internas\AxoftWCFService\Bats\Release\DBAccess.dll"
>
> **> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'ja-jp'  Key being
>   added: 'ja-jp' Build Error.**

And this error It's the same for every new or existing project that I'm trying to obfuscate.

I've uninstalled Dotfuscator, claeanup registry, cleanup direcotries, but somethign must remain that makes this error does not go away.

Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: I work on the Dotfuscator team. We've released [several versions of Dotfuscator Professional](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-pro-change-log) since 4.9. I recommend upgrading to a newer version. If you still have trouble, as a licensed user of Dotfuscator Professional you have access to [PreEmptive Solutions' support](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in Windows Region Settings, specifically the Locale Settings, I change them to my Country, reboot computer, and the problems was solved. Thanks you all.